# Jenkins GUI discrepancy

Tags: jenkins, hudson

There's an issue I'm facing with Jenkins where builds are not visible in the GUI:
[image: GUI showing missing builds]
But as I look at the job's directory on the server, I can see the builds directories in place:
[image: jenkins server builds directory]

Has anyone faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the job configuration you can set the number of historic builds show in the history of job, try increasing that number and check.